# Release pre-Android L app

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to release an app on the Play Store for devices that only run pre-Android L?

I was wondering because one of the API's being deprecated is crucial to my app.

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="whatever your min is"
android:targetSdkVersion="whatever your target is"
android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
```

This will set the maxSdkVersion that your app will work on to 4.4.4

Comment: `maxSdkVersion` in `<uses-sdk>` is ignored by everything, devices and Play Store included.

Comment: what should I do then, CommonsWare?

Comment: According to the documentation:
Future versions of Android (beyond Android 2.0.1) will no longer check or enforce the maxSdkVersion attribute during installation or re-validation. Google Play will continue to use the attribute as a filter, however, when presenting users with applications available for download.